# Return result_array codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tendo a seguinte tabela:

***tbl_atendimento_evento***

```
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`descricao` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`evento_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`devedor_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,    
`negociacao_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`assessoria_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`complemento` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
```

E estou gerando o seguinte array com a função abaixo:

```
public function obter_devedor_evento($devedor_id, $id_negociacao_selecionada)
{    
        $this->db->from('tbl_atendimento_evento');
        $this->db->where('devedor_id',$devedor_id);
        $this->db->where('negociacao_id',$id_negociacao_selecionada);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
}
```

***Array Gerado***

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [descricao] => Envio de e-mail
            [devedor_id] => 1
            [evento_id] => 3
            [negociacao_id] => 3
            [assessoria_id] => 1
            [complemento] => Texto do complemento
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [descricao] => Recado
            [devedor_id] => 1
            [evento_id] => 4
            [negociacao_id] => 3
            [assessoria_id] => 1
            [complemento] => Texto do complemento
        )

)
```

Eu quero saber como posso incluir o campo complemento após a `view`

***Array Pretendido***

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [descricao] => Envio de e-mail
            [devedor_id] => 1
            [evento_id] => 3
            [negociacao_id] => 3
            [assessoria_id] => 1
            [view][complemento] => Texto do complemento
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [descricao] => Recado
            [devedor_id] => 1
            [evento_id] => 4
            [negociacao_id] => 3
            [assessoria_id] => 1
            [view][complemento] => Texto do complemento
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize a função [array_map](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php) e faça os ajustes necessários, não existe mover, cada item deve ser criado e removido quando for desnecessário, exemplo:

```
public function obter_devedor_evento($devedor_id, $id_negociacao_selecionada)
{    
        $this->db->from('tbl_atendimento_evento');
        $this->db->where('devedor_id',$devedor_id);
        $this->db->where('negociacao_id',$id_negociacao_selecionada);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return array_map(function($item){
            $item['view']['complemento'] = $item['complemento']; // adiciona nova chave
            unset($item['complemento']); // remove a chave que não precisa
            return $item;
        }, $query->result_array());
}
```

Comment: Hum, perfeito, funcionou mesmo.
Se for o caso de adicionar outros itens a view, como pode ser feito ?

Comment: Devo repetir  `item` e `unset` dentro do array_map?

Comment: @WagnerFilho a lógica para adicionar é `$item['view']['nova _ chave']  = valor `

Comment: @WagnerFilho a lógica para remover é `unset($item['nome _ da _ chave']);`

Comment: Certo, tentei e consegui.
Obrigado!!

Comment: desculpe a pergunta, mas é possivel usar `unset` em `row_array` ?

Comment: @WagnerFilho no resultado dele sim! é a mesma coisa.

Comment: É porque estou tendo este retorno: `Cannot unset string offsets`, fazendo da seguinte forma:

`return array_map(function($item){
            unset($item['dt_cadastro']);
   unset($item['dt_atualizacao']);
   unset($item['id']);
            return $item;
        },
   
  $query->row_array());`

Comment: O `$query->row_array()` retorna um array simples não precisa interar, porque ele não é uma coleção. coloque `$item = $query->row_array(); ` depois coloque `unset($item['id']);` ou seja, não precisa de `array_map`, talvez nem precise fazer isso já na SQL se pode remover o que não precisa...

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou. Obrigado